# Can't add a user from one domain as manager to a user in anther domain in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to update the manager property of users in one domain to 'users' in another domain.
For this purpose, I am first getting the names from an excel file. On the basis of first name I search the first domain and get the user.
Similarly, on the basis of the second name I search the second domain and get the user. After getting the user from both the domains. I want to set the user (from the second domain) as manager to the user (from the first domain) in AD, but I get the error message

> "Cannot find an object with identity: 'Second User' under: 'DC = bs,DC=cl,DC=com,DC=au'".

Below is the script:

```
Import-Module psexcel
$path = "C:\Users\muh\testFile2.xlsx"
Import-XLSX -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    $ADUser  =  (Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Store)'" -Server server1.bs.cl.com.au).Name
    $manager = (Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($_.Name)'" -Server server2.cl.com.au).Name
if ($ADUser -And $manager)
{
   $ADUser | Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser -Manager $manager -Server server1.bs.cl.com.au
}
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `.Name` to `.DistinguishedName`

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? And why are you getting the manager's user account twice?

Comment: Its throwing the error in the last statement. Sorry, I was trying some random stuff that's why I was getting the manager's user account twice. I have edited the question. Please review the question. Thanks :)

Comment: you shouldn't be getting the objects `.Name`. Leave the AD Principals as they are, `Set-ADUser -Manager <ADUser>` (meaning, the parameter can take an AD User as argument)

Comment: Thank you very much @SantiagoSquarzon :) it resolved the issue. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments, the issue comes due to the expansion of the `.Name` property of the users when, `Set-ADUser` knows how to set an AD User object as it is.

The following would solve the problem:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\muh\testFile2.xlsx'
Import-XLSX -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($user = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Store)'" -Server server1.bs.cl.com.au) {
        if($manager = Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($_.Name)'" -Server server2.cl.com.au) {
            $user | Set-ADUser -Manager $manager -Server server1.bs.cl.com.au
        }
    }
}
```