# Updating properties in Azure AD while using directory sync from on-premise

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a setup with multiple on-premise domains, which all synchronize to a common Azure AD.

The problem now is that we have people in one domain that are managers of people in other domains.

When trying to set the manager property in Azure AD using my code I get the following error:

> Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration

I try updating like this

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateManagerForUser(string userId, string managerId)
        {   
            try
            {
                await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Manager.Reference.Request().PutAsync(managerId);

                return true;
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Can it not be done? Or is there a solution for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if you try to update properties of users synced from **on-premises domains** via Azure AD Connect to Azure AD cloud directly.

I have below users synced from **on-premises domains** to my Azure AD tenant:

[image]

When I ran below sample code to assign **`admanager`** as Manager of **`aduser1`**, I too got **same error** as you:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.ReferenceUpdate
{
    OdataId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<admanagerID>",
};

try
{
    await graphClient.Users["aduser1Id"].Manager.Ref.PutAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully added manager");
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, it's **not possible** to update properties of on-premises synced users directly via Portal or Graph API.
>
> Instead, you need to update the `manager` property in **on-premises** Active Directory first and then synchronize these changes to Azure AD via Azure AD Connect.

In my case, I added  **`admanager`** as Manager of **`aduser1`** in **on-premises** Active Directory like below:

[image]

Once synchronization is done via Azure AD connect, **`aduser1`** is updated with **Manager** property successfully in Portal:

[image]

You can also retrieve the updated **manager** property using below Microsoft Graph API query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/aduser1@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/manager
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Sample c# code:**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var result = await graphClient.Users["aduser1@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"].Manager.GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you prefer adding user from one domain as **manager** to a user in another domain in **on-premises** Active Directory  via PowerShell, check this [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895523/cant-add-a-user-from-one-domain-as-manager-to-a-user-in-anther-domain-in-ad) by *@Santiago Squarzon*

Answer (score 0):

The multi-forest manager problem is a common and long-standing Active Directory limitation that is well-described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/zst4ap/ad_aad_and_crossforest_manager_attributes/jvttrlh/?context=3).

In essence, the solution is based on Azure AD Connect. Azure AD Connect supports synchronization from multiple forests and consolidation of duplicate user objects across these forests. Creating “shadow” representations of users in each relevant forest allows Azure AD Connect to sync managers and direct reports from different forests.

This limitation increasingly impacts Teams and Governance deployment so I've written up [a solution](https://mindline.com/august-8-synchronizing-multi-forest-managers-to-azure-ad/).